# get Object data from Firestore with order

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get object data from firestore

[image]

the problem is that although I saved the data as

command, damage, frame, state, way

when I get the data from firestore in React,

[image]

the order of the object is shuffled.

For example,

frame, range, command, damage, hitframe

range, hitframe, frame, command, damage,

etc...

I want it to be orderd as command, damage, frame, state, way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s how you can sort an object by its keys/properties, alphabetically:

```html
<script>
  const unordered = {
    'frame': 'foo',
    'range': 'bar',
    'command': 'baz',
    'damage': 'hit',
    'hitframe': 'no'
  };

  console.log(JSON.stringify(unordered));
  // → '{'frame': 'foo', 'range': 'bar','command': 'baz','damage': 'hit','hitframe': 'no'}'

  const ordered = Object.keys(unordered).sort().reduce(
    (obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = unordered[key];
      return obj;
    },
    {}
  );

  console.log(JSON.stringify(ordered));
  // → '{"command":"baz","damage":"hit","frame":"foo","hitframe":"no","range":"bar"}'
</script>
```

In this way, you will be able to get your objects in alphabetical order. Mention if you need anything else.

Comment: If this is the answer that you were looking for then please upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

The data is saved as array and as such sorted by the array index. I would recommend thatyou just sort the data on client side when receiving it using the [JavaScript sort array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).